# Delay pop up tag with lazy load

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, oclazyload, jquery-lazyload

I want this popup tag can be loaded after 60 seconds of full page load with Lazy load or jquery. because settimeout and setinterval never worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var adfly_id = 17670577;
    var adfly_protocol = 'https';
    var popunder_frequency_delay = 0;
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.ay.gy/js/display.js"></script>
```

thank you for your help

Comment: setTimeout and setInterval always worked for me. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Why did settimeout and setinterval never work?

Comment: what popup? does the `display.js` automatically loads the popup?

Comment: yes setTimeout and setInterval never worked even i have demand help from freelancer dotcom, andrei yes display.js load popup automatically

Comment: can you define 'setTimeout and setInterval never worked'?

Comment: yes never worked

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` presumably isn't working because `display.js` is a wad of self-invoking `eval()`, so there isn't an obvious thing to wrap the `setTimeout` around.

But as long as that external code doesn't depend on the window onload event, you should be able to `setTimeout` the insertion of the script itself:

```
// jQuery:
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $.getScript('https://cdn.ay.gy/js/display.js');
  // see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript
}, 60000);

// or without jQuery:
window.setTimeout(function() {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute( 'src', 'https://cdn.ay.gy/js/display.js' );
  document.body.appendChild( s );
}
```